# Why the drop downs are not getting hide and show based on value selected from the select box in following case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, jsfiddle

Following is the concerned HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select#classroom").change(function () {

      $("select#classroom").val() === 'traditional' ? $('.block-time-term.checkbox-grid').show() : $('.block-time-term.checkbox-grid').hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
                      <select name="classroom" id="classroom" style="height:50px; width:100%; font-size:13px;" onchange="classroomChnage();">
                        <option  value="traditional">Traditional Classroom</option>
                        <option  value="online">Online Classroom</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

<div class="block-time-term" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                      <!--<div class="pages_type_add_form_input" id="class_time">Class Timing            </div>-->
                      <label style="margin-top:5px;">Starts at :</label>
                      <select name="hours_start" id="hours_start" style="font-size:13px;">
                        <option value="">hh</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="minutes_start" id="minutes_start" style="font-size:13px;">
                        <option value="">mm</option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="am_pm_start" id="am_pm_start" style="font-size:13px;">
                        <option value="AM">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>        
                      </select>
                      <br><br>
                      <label style="margin-top:5px;">Ends at :</label>
                      <select name="hours_end" id="hours_end" style="margin-left:7px; font-size:13px;">
                        <option value="">hh</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="minutes_end" id="minutes_end" style="font-size:13px;">
                        <option value="">mm</option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="am_pm_end" id="am_pm_end" style="font-size:13px;">
                        <option value="AM">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>        
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="checkbox-grid">
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_all_grp_day" value="value1" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label>All</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Mon" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text2">Mon</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Tue" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text3">Tue</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Wed" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text4">Wed</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Thu" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text5">Thu</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Fri" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text6">Fri</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Sat" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text7">Sat</label></li>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Sun" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text8">Sun</label></li>
                    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to hide the select controls when user selects the option "Online Classroom" and the same should be displayed when user selects "Traditional Classroom".

I've written all the code but not understanding why its' not functioning? It's not hiding and showing the drop downs?
Please help me.

Following is the fiddle link. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qbj21pbj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're looking for a class called "block-time-term" that also has a class called "checkbox-grid":

```
$(".block-time-term.checkbox-grid")
```

but your HTML just has `.block-time-term`:

```
<div class="block-time-term" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
```

so change to:

```
$("select#classroom").val() === 'traditional' ? $('.block-time-term').show() : $('.block-time-term').hide();
```

or add that class

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbj21pbj/4/)

you can also remove `onchange="classroomChnage();` from your `select`, it's not effecting anything but it is throwing an error

**UPDATE**

Two target both classes at the same time you just need to separate them with a `,` :

```
$("select#classroom").val() === 'traditional' ? $('.block-time-term, .checkbox-grid').show() : $('.block-time-term, .checkbox-grid').hide();
```

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbj21pbj/5/)

Comment: But the second dropdown showing the day names is still visible it's not getting hidden. I want to hide that dropdown as well. How to do that? Can we do it in a same code line simultaneously instead of writing two codes separately? I tried it but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Just give space between class name and make the ul within the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#classroom").change(function () {
            $(this).val() === 'traditional' ? $('.block-time-term .checkbox-grid').show() : $('.block-time-term .checkbox-grid').hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <select name="classroom" id="classroom" style="height:50px; width:100%; font-size:13px;" onchange="classroomChnage();">
    <option  value="traditional">Traditional Classroom</option>
    <option  value="online">Online Classroom</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="block-time-term" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    <!--<div class="pages_type_add_form_input" id="class_time">Class Timing            </div>-->
    <label style="margin-top:5px;">Starts at :</label>
    <select name="hours_start" id="hours_start" style="font-size:13px;">
    <option value="">hh</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select name="minutes_start" id="minutes_start" style="font-size:13px;">
    <option value="">mm</option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    </select>
    <select name="am_pm_start" id="am_pm_start" style="font-size:13px;">
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM">PM</option>        
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label style="margin-top:5px;">Ends at :</label>
    <select name="hours_end" id="hours_end" style="margin-left:7px; font-size:13px;">
    <option value="">hh</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select name="minutes_end" id="minutes_end" style="font-size:13px;">
    <option value="">mm</option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    </select>
    <select name="am_pm_end" id="am_pm_end" style="font-size:13px;">
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM">PM</option>        
    </select>

    <ul class="checkbox-grid">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_all_grp_day" value="value1" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label>All</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Mon" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text2">Mon</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Tue" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text3">Tue</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Wed" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text4">Wed</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Thu" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text5">Thu</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Fri" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text6">Fri</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Sat" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text7">Sat</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="val[grp_day][]" value="Sun" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><label for="text8">Sun</label></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```